# Is it possible to limit a TFS query to top 100?

Tags: tfs, wiql

Using TFS (hosted), I'm trying to create a query to show some stats about the top 100 product backlog items.

I can add a condition to filter by the "Backlog Priority" field, but these numbers are arbitrary and the query would require constant manual updates. I want to filter by backlog position (called "Order" in the Product Backlog view).

I have tried saving a .wiq file from the query editor, manually adding `TOP 100`, and reopening the .wiq file. I get the error "TF51006: The query statement is missing a FROM clause. The error is caused by «100».

Is it possible to accomplish this through the TFS website? If not, is it possible to create this query in WIQL and save it to the server?